# Write text on the video and display on the player with the best conditions

Tags: video, ffmpeg, jwplayer7

I have this code for watermark a text on the video:

```
ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile='arialbd.ttf': font=arialbd: text='SiteName.local': fontsize=18: fontcolor=white: x=10:y=h-th-10" -acodec copy -y out2.mp4
```

Then I want to play it by `jwplayer`.

When I input a video with normal size (ex. 500x300px), all things is ok and it's preview player:

[image: 500x300px]
*(The text on image is with good size.)*

But if the video has big size (ex. 1500x900px) it's preview player:

[image: 1500x900px]
*(The text on image is illegible.)*

Or if the video has very small size (ex. 150x90px) it's preview player:

[image: 150x90px]
*(The text on image is covered on video.)*

I know reason of this happen is `fontsize` in `ffmpeg` command.

Now I thinks must get `width` and `height` of the video and then with calculation and discovery of a formula, and find the best `fontsize` for usage. If you agree, what's the best formula?!

Or maybe I should not use `fontsize`! and I can use parameters in `ffmpeg` command for reach the goal?!

What's your idea?

Comment: Are you re-encoding just so you can add the text? You can [use the player to overlay a logo or text instead](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1406865-branding-your-player).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard No, change encoding for have a standard format for playing all videos on player is important for me. also, with watermark in encoding, the user can not remove it from video.